# Python: Comparing dictionaries for multiple scenarios

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, compare

I'm comparing dictionaries of server files that contain up to 100,000 results.

I have captured a list file from my servers, and I have read them into dictionaries in my program. The key values are an md5 hash, and the v values are a path (i.e /usr/john/upstart.exe).

My dictionaries are named `firstServ` and `secondServ`.

I need to find out where:

- keys and values that are completely unique to firstServ or secondServ.
- K in the firstServ is different from k in secondServ, but associated values are the same
- Finally, where the keys are the same but the values are different.(hypothetically this should not happen, but it will verify how clean the data is.)

Basically, I just need to know how to make those comparisons. Thank you for any input.

Comment: Can you editing providing example code and example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple idea is the following;

```
FirstSet = {"1":"C:/", "2":"C:/Windows", "3":"C:/Users","4":"C:/Something"}
SecondSet = {"10":"E:/", "20":"C:/", "30":"C:/Users"}

Differences = []

for i in FirstSet.keys():
    if(FirstSet[i] not in SecondSet.values()):
        Differences.append((FirstSet[i],"FirstSet"))


for i in SecondSet.keys():
    if(SecondSet[i] not in FirstSet.values()):
        Differences.append((SecondSet[i],"SecondSet"))


for i in Differences:
    print("Only set {} has the {} element.".format(i[1],i[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There would be a 101 ways to do this.

Maybe load your key,value pairs into something like this:

```
x = { k: [v1,v2] }
```

Then you will have the data from firstServ and secondServ together grouped by hash.  Just loop through the dictionary and find where things are different.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension and simple for loops you can do that:

Given these dictionnaries:

```
firstServ = {"md5Hash1":"path1", "md5Hash2":"path2", "md5Hash3":"path3"}
secondServ = {"md5Hash1":"path4", "md5Hash4":"path2", "md5Hash5":"path5"}
```

Extract the keys:

```
firstServKeys = set(firstServ.keys())
secondServKeys = set(secondServ.keys())
```

**Keys unique to firstServ**

Substract secondServKeys from firstServKeys

```
uniqueKeysInFirstServ = firstServKeys.difference(secondServKeys)
```

**Keys unique to secondServ**

Substract firstServKeys from secondServKeys

```
uniqueKeysInSecondServ = secondServKeys.difference(firstServKeys)
```

**Values present in both dictionaries with different keys**

Invert both maps from {hash:path} to {path:hash}, then for all path in inv_festServ, lookup if inv_festServ has it too, and keep if their hash are different.

```
inv_festServ = {v: k for k, v in firstServ.items()}  # Inverting keys and values
inv_secondServ = {v: k for k, v in secondServ.items()}  # Inverting keys and values
valuesWithDifferentkeys = [v for v in list(inv_festServ.keys()) 
    if v in inv_secondServ.keys() and inv_secondServ[v] != inv_festServ[v]]
```

**Keys present in both dictionaries with different values**

Intersect firstServKeys and secondServKeys to have all the common keys, this way we work on a smaller set
Then for each key, keep if the values are different

```
keysWithDifferentValues = [k for k in firstServKeys.intersection(secondServKeys) 
    if firstServ[k] != secondServ[k]]
```

Print out:

```
print("Keys unique to first server:")
print(uniqueKeysInFirstServ)
print("Keys unique to second server:")
print(uniqueKeysInSecondServ)
print("Values present in both servers but with a different key:")
print(valuesWithDifferentkeys)
print("Keys present in both servers but with a different value:")
print(keysWithDifferentValues)
```

outputs

```
Keys unique to first server:
{'md5Hash2', 'md5Hash3'}

Keys unique to second server:
{'md5Hash5', 'md5Hash4'}

Values present in both servers but with a different key:
['path2']

Keys present in both servers but with a different value:
['md5Hash1']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked out really well, and helped me with parts of the code unmentioend :)